# haproxy - how to share a session between two different tomcats

Tags: session, tomcat, load-balancing, haproxy

Is it possible to share a session among 2 tomcats that runs the same web application and which is both balanced by haproxy? (haproxy is round robin based, and not using sticky-session)

by sharing i mean creating the session in one place (haproxy or tomcat) and be able to get it from the other tomcat.

(our goal is statless web application servers)..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You can cluster your tomcat servers together.

> **Configure Tomcat to Share Sessions**
>
> The key to enable session sharing is to declare two XML elements: one
>   in your application's web.xml (1) and the other in Tomcat's server.xml
>   (2):
>
> 1. `<distributable />`
> 2. `<Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster" />`

**Important Note:** Your session attributes **must** be serializable.

**Sources**:

- [Krams - Clustering and Load Balancing...](http://krams915.blogspot.sg/2011/10/tomcat-clustering-and-load-balancing_09.html) - very detailed step-by-step guide.
- [Apache - Clustering HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/cluster-howto.html) - manual.